# HTML internal link checker

Tags: html, hyperlink, scripting

I'm looking for a link checker for HTML documents. Not for a website: for an HTML document, or a small collection of HTML documents. My constraints:

- It must work on a collection of HTML files passed on the command line, without involving a web server.
- It must be able to work without network access. Ideally it should have a command line option to indicate whether to check whether HTTP links are live.
- It must check internal anchors and must support `id` attributes on any element. My primary use case is checking HTML files generated from Markdown by Pandoc or from reStructuredText by Sphinx.
- It must work in a build-and-test automated pipeline, so no GUI or browser-based tools.
- It must report the broken links in a usable way so I know what to fix if the validation fails.
- It must work on Linux, macOS and Windows (Cygwin or WSL is ok).
- It should be easy to set up even in an environment where we scrutinize all installed software for security. In particular I'd like to avoid a dependency on JavaScript ecosystems. Python would be preferred because that's our default scripting language, but I don't care what language the tool is written in, it's just to minimize extra dependencies. Ideally, the installation should only involve `apt-get` on Ubuntu or `pip3 install`.
- It must be free for commercial use and preferably have a well-known open source license (so that there's no concern about installing it in a corporate environment — but I don't absolutely need to be able to redistribute it).

Comment: Did you have a look at  W3D-LinkChecker (a.o. https://github.com/w3c/link-checker.git)?

Comment: @albert Thanks, it looks promising. I'd skipped it because the Ubuntu package has a dependency on Apache, but I notice now that it's only a recommendation, and it does look like it can operate on local files. I'll give it a try.